# detox react native: Support for es6 imports in test specs js files

Tags: detox

In my test spec file, I am importing an es6 module using import statement. I am using jest test-runner and getting following error-

Cannot find module *warnOnce* from *react-native-implementation.js*

I edited ./e2e/config.json to add following configuration-

```
"preset": "react-native",
"transform": {
    "^.+\\.js$": "../node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js"
 }
```

But then I started getting errors-
Cannot find module *Platform* from *react-native-implementation.js*

My .babelrc content-

```
{
  "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"],
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", {"legacy": true}]
  ]
}
```

I tried replacing .babelrc with babel.config.js with similar content but got no luck. I was using mocha initially but switched to jest thinking that jest will have this support out of box.